# Beamer-Metropolis: change font size for section pages

Tags: beamer, beamer-metropolis

I am using the metropolis theme for Beamer, but I find the font on section pages too big (as big as presentation title). I try to reduce it, but the setbeamerfont seems to only affect placement of the section title, not its size. Am I doing something wrong?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}          
\setbeamerfont{section page}{size=\footnotesize} % only shifts placement
\begin{document}
  \section{First Section}
  \begin{frame}{First Frame}
    Hello, world!  
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This problem seems to happen with either PDFLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme          
\setbeamerfont{section title}{size=\footnotesize}
\begin{document}
  \section{First Section}
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{First Frame}
    Hello, world!  
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I wish the list of beamer elements were easier to navigate!

Comment: @Peutch May be this list helps you: [Beamer Appearance Cheat Sheet](http://www.cpt.univ-mrs.fr/~masson/latex/Beamer-appearance-cheat-sheet.pdf)